# java printerjob landscape white space

Tags: java, graphics, printing, orientation

i currently have an issue with my printerjob, it works great for portrait images, but for landscape images, it cuts part of the image and fills in a white space instead.

This is my code

**EDIT**

```
PrintService printService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File("house.jpg"));

boolean isLandscape = bufferedImage.getWidth() > bufferedImage.getHeight();
PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
printerJob.setPrintService(printService);
printerJob.setCopies(copies);

PageFormat pageFormat = printerJob.defaultPage();
pageFormat.setOrientation(isLandscape ? PageFormat.LANDSCAPE : PageFormat.PORTRAIT);

Paper paper = new Paper();
paper.setSize(pageFormat.getWidth(), pageFormat.getHeight());
paper.setImageableArea(0.0, 0.0, paper.getWidth(), paper.getHeight());

pageFormat.setPaper(paper);

printerJob.setPrintable(new Printable(){
   @Override
   public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException{
       if (pageIndex == 0) {
          Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)graphics;
          double xScale = 1;
          double xTranslate = 0;
          double yScale = 1;
          double yTranslate = 0;
          double widthScale = (pageFormat.getImageableWidth() / bufferedImage.getWidth()) * xScale;
          double heightScale = (pageFormat.getImageableHeight() / bufferedImage.getHeight()) * yScale;

          AffineTransform affineTransform = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(widthScale, heightScale);
          affineTransform.translate(xTranslate, yTranslate);

          g2.drawRenderedImage(bufferedImage, affineTransform);
          g2.translate((int)pageFormat.getImageableX(), (int)pageFormat.getImageableY());

          return PAGE_EXISTS;
       }else return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
   }
}, pageFormat);

printerJob.print();
```

This allows me to print portrait pictures to fit the given paper and without borders (fit to paper), i need it to do the same for landscape pictures please.

This are examples of what happens when i try with a portrait and landscape image so u see what i mean. The images should always fit to the paper size and borderless, which in this case is 10x15cm,

Portrait image: 
[image]

Landscape image:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `PageFormat#getWidth` or `PageFormat#getHeight`, use `PageFormat#getImageableWidth` and `PageFormat#getImageableHeight` instead

From the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/PageFormat.html)

> Return the height/width, in 1/72nds of an inch, of the imageable area of the page. This method takes into account the orientation of the page.

You should also translate the printer `Graphics` by the `ImageableX/Y`...

```
g2.translate((int)pageFormat.getImageableX(), (int)pageFormat.getImageableY());
```

**Runnable example**

This is a simple runnable example.  This code was able to take the original (left) and print it both in portrait and landscape without issue...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class PrintTest100 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
                    pj.setJobName(" Print Component ");

                    PageFormat pf = pj.defaultPage();
//                  pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
//                  pf = pj.validatePage(pf);

                    pj.setPrintable(new ImagePrintable(ImageIO.read(new File("..."))), pf);

                    if (!pj.printDialog()) {
                        return;
                    }
                    try {
                        pj.print();
                    } catch (PrinterException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (IOException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static class ImagePrintable implements Printable {

        private int currentPage = -1;
        private Image cachedScaledImage = null;

        private BufferedImage master;

        public ImagePrintable(BufferedImage master) {
            this.master = master;
        }

        public double getScaleFactor(int iMasterSize, int iTargetSize) {
            double dScale = 1;
            if (iMasterSize > iTargetSize) {
                dScale = (double) iTargetSize / (double) iMasterSize;
            } else {
                dScale = (double) iTargetSize / (double) iMasterSize;
            }
            return dScale;
        }

        public double getScaleFactorToFit(BufferedImage img, Dimension size) {
            double dScale = 1;
            if (img != null) {
                int imageWidth = img.getWidth();
                int imageHeight = img.getHeight();
                dScale = getScaleFactorToFit(new Dimension(imageWidth, imageHeight), size);
            }
            return dScale;
        }

        public double getScaleFactorToFit(Dimension original, Dimension toFit) {
            double dScale = 1d;
            if (original != null && toFit != null) {
                double dScaleWidth = getScaleFactor(original.width, toFit.width);
                double dScaleHeight = getScaleFactor(original.height, toFit.height);

                dScale = Math.min(dScaleHeight, dScaleWidth);
            }
            return dScale;
        }

        @Override
        public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {

            int result = Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;

            if (pageIndex == 0) {

                result = Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;

                Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D) graphics;
                graphics2D.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());

                int width = (int) Math.round(pageFormat.getImageableWidth());
                int height = (int) Math.round(pageFormat.getImageableHeight());

                if (currentPage != pageIndex || cachedScaledImage == null) {
                    currentPage = pageIndex;

                    double scaleFactor = getScaleFactorToFit(new Dimension(master.getWidth(), master.getHeight()), new Dimension(width, height));

                    int imageWidth = (int) Math.round(master.getWidth() * scaleFactor);
                    int imageHeight = (int) Math.round(master.getHeight() * scaleFactor);

                    cachedScaledImage = master.getScaledInstance(imageWidth, imageHeight, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

                }

                double x = ((pageFormat.getImageableWidth() - cachedScaledImage.getWidth(null)) / 2);
                double y = ((pageFormat.getImageableHeight() - cachedScaledImage.getHeight(null)) / 2);

                graphics2D.drawImage(cachedScaledImage, (int) x, (int) y, null);
                graphics2D.setColor(Color.RED);
                graphics2D.drawRect(0, 0, width - 1, height - 1);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

}
```

nb: I had an issue with Yosemite, trying to figure out how to change the print orientation from the dialog, in the end, I gave up and forced it by changing the `PageFormat` from the `PrintJob`.  I've used this same type of code in countless applications without issues before...

**Updated**

Original Image: 1920x1200

[image]

Comment: i did what u said, replaced getWidth and getHeight for getImageableWidth and getImageableHeight.... i also added the g2.translate line after g2.drawrenderedimage ... if i print portrait image its good but for landscape now it cuts the image even more...it remove the left and right size of the picture and just positions part of the image on the center of the paper. See edit

Comment: Check update, with runnable example, works fine for me

Comment: thanks but it still doesnt fill the paper on landscape, it cuts the landscape image, the left and right side. It just prints the center of the image

Comment: Your affine transform is compounding.  Instead of scaling and translating, try translating the graphics context first.  I've avoid using `AffineTransform` in this case for, in part, this reason

Comment: I am stuck, i am currently using the runnable code you posted. i gave it a 1800x1200 landscape image and the result is that lamborghini landscape picture u see on my post up there, as you can see, it doesn't fill up the whole paper.

Comment: Is that your own print preview code? Have you tried printing it to the printer using the example code?

Comment: thats the print preview window of my print device EPSON L800... and i tried printing it on actual paper and appear as the preview said it would

Comment: That would suggest that there is something wrong with how the print driver translates the graphics, as this approach has worked on just about every other printed I've used it on. It "seems" lie the x position is been translated incorrectly. You might try use the negative of imageableX or translate the x position as 0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and changed the ImageableArea:

```
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        job.setJobName("Folha de Bateria");
        
        PageFormat pageFormat = job.defaultPage();
        pageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
        
        Paper paper = pageFormat.getPaper();
        paper.setImageableArea(paper.getImageableX() - 100, paper.getImageableY() - 100, paper.getImageableWidth() + 200, paper.getImageableHeight() + 200);
        pageFormat.setPaper(paper);
        
        job.setPrintable(new SheetPrinter(getSelectedStep()), pageFormat);
        
        boolean doPrint = job.printDialog();
        
        if (doPrint) {
            try {
                job.print();
            } catch (PrinterException e) {
                throw new CoreException(e);
            }
        }
```