# Java - Landscape Printing Doesn't Work

Tags: java, printing

I have the following code in Java SE8:

```
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

        PageFormat pf1 = job.defaultPage();
        pf1.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
        PageFormat pf2 = job.validatePage(pf1);

        job.setPrintable(myPrintable, pf2);
        job.print();
```

I want to print my page in the landscape mode. But it is not working properly. The landscape mode only applies at painting time! I mean that the image I'm painting to g2d in `Printable#print()` does rotate; I have no blank area on my page (there would be a blank area if `setOrientation` wasn't called) but the page remains portrait when printed, its width being less than its height. (It's not scretched. It's rotated back after painting!)

Where is the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I went back and tested [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033691/java-printerjob-landscape-white-space/27033735#27033735) without any issues.  Perhaps considering providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I just ran your example. It's doing the same thing. It just rotates the printed image not the whole page... I'm wondering if Java has the feature at all...!!

Comment: @MadProgrammer I also tried `PageFormat pf1 = job.pageDialog(job.defaultPage());` and manually set it to landscape, but nothing changed.

Comment: I also tried different virtual printers, all working well in Microsoft Word landscape printing, but not in Java!

Comment: So, you want the content rotated to match the page orientation?

Comment: I want to rotate the page and the content together. For example when I use a virtual printer, having set it to landscape mode, I expect it to create PDF pages with their widths more than their heights. But It gives me portrait pages with their content rotated. This may be satisfying when using a real printer, since users can manually put the papers inside the printer in right orientation, but not when the user chooses to use a virtual printer, because portrait PDF pages with rotated contents are usually useless (unreadable).

Comment: Best thing you can do is rotate the `Graphics` context in the `print` method

Comment: But this is exactly what `setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE)` is doing for me...! I want a real paper rotation not a g2d rotation!

Comment: As far as I can tell, and from previous experience, the page/paper is rotated