# how to print a jframe horizontally or give it the printing properties?

Tags: java, netbeans, printing

this is the code that I am using, I need to know where I can change the properties here, because here if I run it, it sends me the print section where you select the printer or give it properties and I need it horizontally and by default it goes vertical

```
public int print(Graphics grap, PageFormat pagFor, int index) throws 
PrinterException {

if (index > 0) 
 {

        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }
    // pagFor.setOrientation(0);

    pagFor.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
    Graphics2D hub = (Graphics2D) grap;

    hub.translate(pagFor.getImageableX() + 5, pagFor.getImageableY());
    hub.scale(0.5, 0.5);

    jPanel1.printAll(grap);

    return PAGE_EXISTS;
}
```

Comment: You need to set the orientation BEFORE printing, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033691/java-printerjob-landscape-white-space/27033735#27033735)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the orientation BEFORE you start printing

```
PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
pj.setJobName("My super-dup awesome print job");

PageFormat pf = pj.defaultPage();
pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
pf = pj.validatePage(pf);

pj.setPrintable(..., pf);

if (!pj.printDialog()) {
    return;
}
try {
    pj.print();
} catch (PrinterException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note: The user may change the orientation in the print dialog, you just need to deal with it in your `Printable`

Comment: that helps me a lot, that was just what I need, and I want to know if I cant avoid the part of the kain of the printer i just want to print in the moment of the click of the button

Comment: You don't need the `if (!pj.printDialog()) {...}` block if you don't want to present the print dialog to the user, but it will print to the default printer